# Воспроизведение потока RTSP в VideoView

Tags: android, videoview

Товарищи прошу помочь.
Задача вывести RTSP  поток в VideoView.
Есть IP камера с которой мне надо забрать поток.
Запускаю vlc плеер и указываю url камеры(rtsp://admin:admin@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/RVi/1/0)
Через несколько секунд появляется видео, vlc плеер мне сообщает тип данных:
H264-MPEG4-AVC(part 10)(h264), на сайте для разработчиков я вижу что этот тип данных поддерживается.

Записываю поток в файл через vlc, полученный файл получается формата H264-MPEG4-AVC. Запихиваю его в папку raw. И следующий код его благополучно воспроизводит:

```
 String videoSource = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;

        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(getActivity());
        videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.requestFocus(); 
        videoView.start();
```

Но у как только я указываю в качестве url -  rtsp://admin:admin@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/RVi/1/0
Система выдает "Не удается воспроизвести видео", а в лог падает "MediaPlayer Error 1 -2147483648"; Вот код:

```
 String videoSource = "rtsp://admin:admin@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/RVi/1/0";

        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(getActivity());
        videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.requestFocus(); 
        videoView.start();
```

Если передать rtps стоку нативному плееру, то видео заработает(на android 4.4 Lenovo), и не заработает на android(4.2.2 Samsung Tab)

Подскажите где копать?, может сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: можете начать с гугла. По запросу `android rtsp videoview` выдается очень много результатов, 4 первых ссылки (кто бы мог подумать) дают ответы.

Comment: Просмотрел кучу всего, ответа так и не нашел. Разрешения в манифесте и на инет и на wifi